# form_tag with default input fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I want to create a custom form_tag helper for my views with some default `fields` like this:

```
=form_tag(url) do
  -fields.each do |name, value|
    =hidden_field_tag name, value
```

but when in my FormHelper class I write something like:

```
def my_form_tag
  form_tag(url) do
   fields.each do |name, value|
     hidden_field_tag name, value
   end
 end
end
```

None of the the `hidden_field_tags` are added.
It seems only the result of the block is displayed. In this case nothing but if I add something like `hidden_field_tag 'name', 'value'` at the end of the block, it will be displayed.
So how can I display all the different fields?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting `fields` from?

Comment: `fields` is just a simple hash that that I want to loop over. Using `map` and `join` seems to have done the trick though. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so instead of doing an `each` I do a `map` and `join` with `html_safe`

```
def my_form_tag
  form_tag(url) do
    fields.map do |name, value|
      hidden_field_tag name, value
    end.join.html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue - `fields` is not declared anywhere

Comment: As stated above fields is just a hash. Let's say it is `fields = {key1: 'key1', key2: 'key2'}`. I didn't declare `url` either let's say it is `url = 'http://myurl.com'`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing partial with this form_tag, and then in your my_form_tag method just render this partial. This way you get the whole form.